# How do I check if a pandas Series is merely initialised (i.e. empty) or defined?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to distinguish between a pandas Series that has merely been initialised, and one that has actually been defined and has values. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
labels = pd.Series
print len(labels)
print labels.empty
```

I get:

- TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
- property object

Then, I define the Series:

```
labels = pd.Series([0, 1, 1]).unique()
print labels.empty
print len(labels)
```

This time I get:

- 2
- AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'empty'

How can I check is a Series is empty or not - getting True or False in return?

Comment: In the first instance you took a reference to the method `Series` which is why you get the error which is not the same as an empty series : `labels = pd.Series()` would output the expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance you took a reference to the method `Series`:

```
In [31]:

labels = pd.Series
print(type(labels))
labels = pd.Series
print(type(labels))
<class 'type'>
```

hence all the errors, you want empty parentheses to make an empty series:

```
In [33]:
labels = pd.Series()
print(labels.empty)
print(len(labels))

True
0
```

In the second instance `unique` returns a numpy array which has no method `empty`, a pandas `Series` does.

```
In [38]:
labels = pd.Series([0, 1, 1]).unique()
type(labels)

Out[38]:
numpy.ndarray
```

You can use `size` attribute to check the dimensions:

```
In [42]:
labels = pd.Series([0, 1, 1]).unique()
print(labels.size)

2
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'empty', when the Series has been defined, instead of False.

Comment: Update your question with code rather than commenting the errors so there is no ambiguity

Comment: In the second instance `unique` returns a numpy array, this has no method for `empty` `Series` does

Comment: Ah okay, I redefined labels as `labels = pd.Series(labels)` and that worked. Thanks!